# C++ boost::range::remove_erase does not work on std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, boost, erase

The code snippet

```
std::map<int, int> m = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
boost::range::remove_erase_if(
    m,
    [](const auto& it)
    {
        return it.first == 1;
    });
```

produces the error

```
12>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133

\include\xmemory(1986,1): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<const int,int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
12>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\utility(269,11): message : could be 'std::pair<const int,int> &std::pair<const int,int>::operator =(volatile const std::pair<const int,int> &)'
12>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(1986,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::pair<const int,int>, std::pair<const int,int>)'
```

I expected remove_erase_if to remove the first pair {1, 2} from the map.

remove_erase_if behaves as expected when I try it with a vector instead of a map:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
boost::range::remove_erase_if(
    v,
    [](const auto& it)
    {
        return it == 1;
    });
```

Here v contains {2, 3, 4} after execution. What do I have to adjust, to use remove_erase_if with a map?

Comment: But am I not accessing that pairs key with it.first?

Comment: `it` is a very confusing variable name. Can't you use `std::erase_if` from C++20? At least that works. `std::erase_if(m, [](const auto& pair) { return pair.first == 1; });`. If you only want to `erase` depending on the _Key_ you may simply use `m.erase(1);`

Comment: I feel like if it works on `vector`, it may never work on `map`. To remove elements from vector, you have to move other elements to new positions. The same is not possible in map, you cannot reassign nodes.

Comment: I saw most implementations so far use ```it``` in such a case but I can see how it's confusing as they type isn't ```iterator```. But that doesn't explain the error.
Unfortunately I cannot use ```std::erase_if``` as our project currently runs on C++17. Otherwise I would've gladly done so. I also had now issues before with ```std::erase_if``` and I can work around it with a classic ```for``` loop. But I would like to understand why the code is not working.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `std::erase_if` works by simply looping through all elements in the map and call `m.erase()` on those where the predicate is `true`. That's a very expensive way of deleting using a _Key_  value.

Comment: _"I cannot use std::erase_if as our project currently runs on C++20"_ - But, as I said, `std::erase_if` _is_ C++20. Why do you want to use `erase_if` on a _Key_? It'll have to look through the whole map. Why not simply do `m.erase(1);` ?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: Sorry, typo. I meant C++17.

Comment: Ok, still. Using `std::erase_if` to remove values according to _Key_ is not the correct thing to do. It's very expensive compared to `m.erase(Key);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was referring to `boost::range::remove_erase_if`. The way you remove elements from `std::vector` and `std::map` is fundamentally different, unless `remove_erase_if` uses metaprogramming to distinguish container types, it can't work on both `std::vector` and `std::map`.

Comment: The example here is just a placeholder to keep it simple. In my actual code the remove condition is more complex. I assume in that case you have to iterate over all map entries and check if the condition is true for each.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes `boost::remove_erase_if` simply does `m.erase(std::remove_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& it) { return it.first == 1; }), m.end());` which doesn't work well on `std::map`. Dennix: I suggest that you just copy the example implementation of [`std::erase_if(std::map)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if). That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `boost::remove_erase_if` will do the same as

```
m.erase(std::remove_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& it) { return it.first == 1; }), m.end());
```

which doesn't work well on `std::map`s.

If you can't use C++20 [`std::erase_if(std::map)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if), make your own. When you later upgrade to C++20, you can replace the `dnx` namespace with `std` in your code that uses `dnx::erase_if`.

```cpp
namespace dnx {
template <class Key, class T, class Compare, class Alloc, class Pred>
typename std::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>::size_type erase_if(
    std::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>& c, Pred pred) {
    auto old_size = c.size();
    for (auto i = c.begin(), last = c.end(); i != last;) {
        if (pred(*i)) {
            i = c.erase(i);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return old_size - c.size();
}
}  // namespace dnx

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    // now works:
    dnx::erase_if(m, [](const auto& it) { return it.first == 1; });
}
```